# Se puede actualizar dinámicamente el view-source de los navegadores?

Tags: vue.js, seo

Tengo una app en vue, que tiene vistas individuales de propiedades. Cuando el usuario entra a ver dicha propiedad, se generan etiquetas `<meta>`, `<title>` y las que haga falta.
Cuando yo entro a la aplicacion e inspecciono el código, veo como se inicia, y luego, al cargar el sitio, se reemplazan los datos (la etiqueta title como mencioné, se reemplaza, y se agregan unos meta datos).

Si yo, en cambio, hago click con el botón derecho en el sitio, y veo en "Ver codigo fuente" (que te lleva a `view-source:http://misitio.com...`) nunca veo el cambio que aplica javascript, sino que veo el titulo que tiene mi `index.html` y no aparecen mis etiquetas `meta`.

Existe alguna manera de indicarle a vue que genere este código antes de renderizarse? Para que sea lo primero que le entregue al navegador.
(cabe aclarar que estoy usando vue 3 sin nuxt y tampoco puedo aplicar SSR por cuestiones de servidor)

> Hecha está pregunta, mi idea es que el robot de google pueda encontrar cada página individual de propiedad. Tal vez lo que yo estoy buscando hacer no hace falta, y los robots la encuentran igual. Pero estoy bastante verde con el SEO.